# Grammatically speaking, why is "I rushed to went back home" wrong?

Tags: grammar

Yesterday I corrected my student when he said: "I rushed to went back home". I corrected it to "I rushed to get back home", but I couldn't provide a proper explanation. I know this is probably basic grammar but I do hope someone can help me out with explaining this properly.

Thank you!

Comment: Actually, you may simply say, "**I rushed back home**" which will be more accurate.

Comment: Ah, that's true! But how can I explain why using "went" is not correct?

Comment: There are many phrases like this. "I wanted to be there", "I wished to go", "I had to leave", "I ordered him to stop", "I asked him to continue", "I like to sing", "I seem to be lost"...  Where there's "to" then it must be the infinitive form after it.

Comment: Not really on topic, but interesting to note that "went" is the past tense form of the verb "to wend". For some reason, that verb more or less died out from English, but its past tense replaced "yode" (to pick one possible spelling) as the past tense of "to go".

Comment: "I rushed back home" may not be more accurate. "I rushed to go back home" means I left where I was quickly, I might have slowed down once I was out the door.

Comment: I rushed to went is like saying 'In the past, I did something in the past.' - besides being redundant, it's a little confusing...

Comment: @user121330 No, to indicate that in the past's past you had already done something, you'd use past perfect: "When my boss was looking for me in the office, she didn't see me there, because I had already rushed to go back home."

Comment: @das-g while I agree that the past's past is past perfect, that isn't the speaker's intention, and the construction in question doesn't specify in the past of the past from when - it's 'before before' as opposed to before some specific action or time before.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've interpreted "In the past, I did something in the past." wrong (or maybe just different) then. I thought you @user121330 were referring to the past's past (though I wasn't claiming that that was the speaker's intention) while you meant that "In the past, I did something" and "I did something in the past" would have been merged to that indeed redundant repetition. Though, even with the redundancy, I think "In the past, I did something in the past." would still be considered grammatical (though slightly nonsensical with the unneeded repetition), while the OPs sentence wouldn't.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A verbal complement of **rushed**  uses the marked infinitive (**to** + VERB, e.g. 
'to go') whereas **went** is a *tensed* (aka finite) form of the verb.

> They rushed **to buy** provisions before the blizzard.
>
> They rushed **to see** the pop star buying chewing gum.
>
> They rushed over to the other side of the ship **to get** a glimpse of the whale.

Comment: +1 You are absolutely right as always. Notice that not only a verb can follow "**rush to**" but also group verbs and nouns. If an adverb follows "**rush to**" then the "*to-infinitive*" is omitted.

Comment: @SovereignSun. A verbal complement is not required, as you indicate, so I've changed it to "*A* verbal complement...".

Comment: @SovereignSun I don't think I understand your comment - are you referring to phrases with an adverb following "rush to" before the verbal complement, e.g. "I rushed to quickly stop the runaway trolley"? If so, isn't that still a "to-infinitive", just split around the adverb?

Comment: @KendallLister I mean, "**I rushed home/forward/up**" and etc.

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer is because "**rush to do something**" is the correct structure and not "*rush to did something*" - wrong!

- I rushed to pack my clothes. *(**Not** "I rushed to packed")*
- I rushed to buy the ticket. *(**Not** "I rushed to bought")*

"**Rush to do something**" means "*to be eager to do something as soon as you can*" or "*to do something very quickly and without delay*"

You could also use the verb "**rush to**" to say "*to go /get somewhere quickly*":

- I rushed back home. *("**home**" is an adverb here that substitutes for "**to**")*
- I rushed to the office immediately.

Comment: The answer is so simple that it doesn't actually explain why "to did" is wrong, as Tᴚoɯɐuo's answer does.

Comment: @MontyHarder Why else would I begin by saying **The simple answer is**. That's what different answers are for.

Comment: @MontyHarder WHY a construction is wrong is never trivial, nor conclusive.  
 Tᴚoɯɐuo's answer provides data that, when combined with a theory of grammar, supports the position that it's wrong, but it isn't any more complete than this answer IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

It's the usage of Infinitive "to do". 'to went' should be 'to go'.

Comment: There's no need in **to go** there either.

Comment: @Sovereign, "I rushed to go back home" is grammatical though, while the OP's statement is not. It's a bit redundant, but it is grammatical.

Comment: @Octopus It is. Nobody says it isn't. But **rush to** already conveys the meaning of **to go/get somewhere quickly**.